# Knockoutjs: Change the color of selected value in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a very simple dropdown populated with values from a view model. When You select 'blue'
I want the color of the selected value to become blue. Is this possible?

html:

```
<select data-bind="options: colors,  value:  selectedColor"></select>
```

javascript:

```
var ColorsViewModel = function() {
  this.colors = ko.observableArray(['blue', 'yellow', 'pink']);
  this.selectedColor = ko.observable('blue');
};

ko.applyBindings(new ColorsViewModel());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/108/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `style` binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: colors,  value:  selectedColor, style: {'background-color': selectedColor}"></select>
```